# Getting WA in Google Kick Start Round A: (Workout Problem)

Tags: c++

## **Problem Description**

Tambourine has prepared a fitness program so that she can become more fit! The program is made of **N** sessions. During the i-th session, Tambourine will exercise for **Mi** minutes. The number of minutes she exercises in each session are strictly increasing.

The difficulty of her fitness program is equal to the maximum difference in the number of minutes between any two consecutive training sessions.

To make her program less difficult, Tambourine has decided to add up to **K** additional training sessions to her fitness program. She can add these sessions anywhere in her fitness program, and exercise any positive integer number of minutes in each of them. After the additional training session are added, the number of minutes she exercises in each session must still be strictly increasing. **What is the minimum difficulty possible?**

**Input**

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, **T**. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the two integers **N** and **K**. The second line contains N integers, the i-th of these is **Mi**, the number of minutes she will exercise in the i-th session.

**Output**

For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and **y is the minimum difficulty possible after up to K additional training sessions are added.**

**Limits**

Time limit: 20 seconds per test set.

Memory limit: 1GB.

1 ≤ T ≤ 100.

For at most 10 test cases, 2 ≤ N ≤ 10^5.

For all other test cases, 2 ≤ N ≤ 300.

1 ≤ Mi ≤ 10^9.

Mi < Mi+1 for all i.

**Test set 1**

K = 1.

**Test set 2**

1 ≤ K ≤ 10^5.

## **MY APPROACH**

Using **Priority Queue**, Extracting Maximum from the Existing elements in the Priority Queue.

**C++ code**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve()
{
    int n,k,x,prev = 0;
    cin>>n>>k;
    priority_queue<int> pq;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        if(prev != 0)
        {
            pq.push(x - prev);
        }
        prev = x;
    }
    while(k > 0 && !pq.empty())
    {
        int tmp = pq.top();
        if(tmp == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        pq.pop();
        pq.push(tmp/2);
        pq.push(tmp - tmp/2);
        k--;
    }
    cout << pq.top() << "\n";
}

int32_t main()
{
    int t,i=1;cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cout << "Case #" << i << ": ";
        solve();
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, dividing adjacent differences by 2 isn't the way to go. If the numbers were 0 and 8 and you were given k = 2, then your algorithm would insert 4 and 6. But instead, it could have just inserted 3 and 6, which is better. *Hint: use a binary search to search for an upper bound*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply splitting by two an interval and replacing it by its two parts cannot work.

For example, your code fails with `n = 2; k = 2; [1 7]`. Your code answer is 3, but 2 is the correct answer.

The idea is to keep trace of the original interval size and the number of times the original interval was split in, together with the length of the longer sub-interval in this interval.

Here is max-heap based solution. The intervals (`struct Interv`) are sorted according of the size of the max length sub-interval. A `std::priority_queue`, as in your code, could have been used too.

This is a greedy algorithm: we decrease the currently largest sub-interval.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Interv {
    int size_div;   // max size of the sub-intervals
    int n_div;      // number of sub-intervals
    int size;       // original size
    friend operator < (const Interv& x, const Interv& y) {
        return x.size_div < y.size_div;
    }
};

int min_step (const std::vector<int>& a, int k) {
    int n = a.size();
    std::vector <Interv> s;
    s.reserve(n);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int d = a[i] - a[i-1];
        s.push_back({d, 1, d});
    }
    std::make_heap (s.begin(), s.end());        // max heap

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (s.empty()) return 1;
        std::pop_heap(s.begin(), s.end());      // max to the back
        Interv p = s.back();                    // get the max
        s.pop_back();
        if (p.size_div == 1) return 1;
        p.n_div++;;
        p.size_div = p.size / p.n_div + (p.size % p.n_div != 0);
        if (p.size_div > 1) s.push_back (p);
        std::push_heap (s.begin(), s.end());    // reorder the heap
    }
    if (s.empty()) return 1;
    std::pop_heap(s.begin(), s.end());
    Interv p = s.back();
    return p.size_div;
}

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); 
    std::cin.tie(NULL); 
    std::cout.tie(0);
    int nt;
    std::cin >> nt;
    for (int t = 1; t <= nt; ++t) {
        int n , k; 
        std::cin >> n >> k;
        std::vector<int> a(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cin >> a[i];
        }
        auto ans = min_step(a, k);
        std::cout << "Case #" << t << ": " << ans << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight @Damien

Comment: If this answers your question, could you please accept it?